# Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device

Tags: android, cordova

Here is my code:

```
fileTransfer.download(
    "http://www.shirleybriceheath.net/pdfs/dummyPDF.pdf",
    "file://sdcard/dummyPDF.pdf", // the key factor !!!
    function(theFile) {
    alert("download complete: " + theFile.toURL());
    console.log("download complete: " + theFile.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
    alert("download error source " + error.source);
    alert("download error target " + error.target);
    alert("upload error code: " + error.code);
    },
    true
);
```

I am first time implementing PDF file downloading in Cordova/Phonegap by using the Cordova file transfer Plugin, but I am getting an error continuously.
In the log I get:

> [ 09-20 10:53:55.402   282:  766 D/         ]
>    Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 0000000F

I tried to find whether I am doing something wrong in the coding part or whether there is there any permission issue, which is not allowing me to download the PDF file, but didn't find any useful solution for that. Please help...